# Wordpress multisite sub pages redirect to home page only firsttime

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, multisite

whenever I opened the subpages (any URL) only the 1st time its redirected to the home page, from the second time its redirected to the correct page.
this is my .htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mydomainname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you actually mean a "redirect" - as in an external 3xx redirect?

Comment: Not external redirect, within my website all the subpages when I click from Whatsapp or paste link first time its redirect to my home page, from the second time it's going to respective URL.

Comment: What counts as the "first time"? Come back 5 mins later and click the link? Or 24+ minutes (the default length of a PHP session)? Maybe the WordPress stack (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask this question? There's nothing wrong with the `.htaccess` code you posted.